# Override default android messaging application

Tags: android, sms, mms

I want to override the default android messaging application. 
If I receive a sms or mms I want to send that to email but i don't want any notification on phone. 
So basically I want to replace the default messaging application.

How can I make my application the default one that receive the sms?

---

Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I need. But I have one more problem.
I used the receiver to get the message ... but I don't know how to find the message in the phone and mark it as read.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //---find and mark the messages as read---
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/");
       try{
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null);
            //---code to find the message by body and sender---
            ...

    }
```

Is there any way in which I can identify the message like an id? 
Now I find the message comparing the bofy and sender number for all messages in inbox.

Thanks, 
Radu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a "default application" in the way you're thinking.  The way applications are dispatched in Android is through `Intents`.  An application wil use an `IntentFilter` to identify that it can handle specific types of `Intents`.  What you're looking for is a `BroadcastReceiver` that can handle the `SMSReceived` intent.  That will allow your application to be notified when an SMS is received.  In order to hide the notification, you will need to mark the SMS as read using the SMS `ContentProvider`.  That will clear the notification out of the notification tray. There is no way to hide a message from the default messaging application unless you delete the message from the SMS `ContentProvider`.  Check out [this link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) for how to get started with `BroadcastReceivers`.

Comment: @MartinBories Thanks for the heads up! I replaced it with one that is working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to block the message from going to the the default messaging app.  If you set the priority of your BroadcastReceiver up high enough (we use 100) and call abortBroadcast to block the intent from being picked up by any lower priority BroadcastReceivers.  It will only work if the intent broadcast is ordered, something that is out of our control.  But it turns out that the SMS_SENT broadcast is ordered, and I suspect the MMS_SENT broadcast is as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you sent priority of your BroadcastReceiver high enough, your application is the first one receiving the message, *BEFORE* the message is stored in the database.
I guess the solution would be to store the message in the database yourself and call `abortBroadcast();`, but I didn't try this myself, yet.

Good luck!