# How to set my application as a default messaging application for SMS and MMS

Tags: android, default, messaging

I would like to set my application as a default messaging application same as what "HandCent SMS" application is doing.

I have also gone through the following link
[Override default android messaging application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752889/override-default-android-messaging-application)

and try to use "abortBroadcast()" but sms is only received by my application is it not getting stored in native inbox.

Please provide some sample code or guideline to proceed on this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you intercepted broadcast for SMS you have to store the new message in the native storage yourself - you can access it using Telephony.SMS (and Sms.CONTENT_URI), though these are not part of the SDK. Sorry, I do not have a sample code for this.

Comment: This would be the workaround anyways, but it does not show unread message count at native messaging app icon.
Except storing again in SMS inbox any other way to achieve this ? Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve? If you're going to replace native messaging - why would you want it to show the counter? Anyway, you could mark it as unread (Sms.READ = false)

Comment: I would like to provide an setting in my application to make my application as a default messaging application for SMS only just [like what "Handcent SMS" application is doing] so that if an SMS received by application then my application should be able to override android native functionality like tone,vibrate,notification etc it should be handled by my application only but SMS should also available at native inbox.

Comment: Tried by using abortBroadcast() and can understand that have to explicitly store SMS again with the help of content provider in native inbox also.(I have not tried with Sms.READ attribute, I'll check that)
But I would like to know does android provides an API or other way around that I could avoid step to write message in device database ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, phoneNumber);
   values.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, message);
   getContentResolver().insert(Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

hey u can do this on android 4.4 and below 4.4 use content resolver URI.