# How do I filter certain SMS in my android Application

Tags: android, sms

i want to write an application that when a certain SMS received ,my application proccess it and not shown in the Message box of my device and for other message just MessageBox of device proccess it,
for example in my code:I want that when a new message with "Dbdmrs4204" on body received just my application notification show it replace message box of my device

**Note:** now My code run with no errore but when text Message with "Dbdmrs4204" in body received two Notification create in both(my app and Message box)

```
public class MyServices extends Service {
public static boolean state = true;
public static LocationManager locationManager;
public static String senderNumber;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

public static class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements
        LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                if (i == 0) {
                    // ---get the sender address/phone number---
                    senderNumber = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

                }
                // ---get the message body---
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }
            // ---display the new SMS message---
            MainActivity.msgRecived = str;
            Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // this.abortBroadcast();
            // IntentFilter myfilter=new IntentFilter();
            // myfilter.setPriority(100);
            if (str.equals("Dbdmrs4204")) {

                NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) G.context
                        .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NotificationCompat.Builder ncomp = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        G.context);
                ncomp.setContentTitle("title ");
                ncomp.setContentText("some text");
                ncomp.setTicker("some text");
                ncomp.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay);
                ncomp.setAutoCancel(true);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(G.context,
                        RequestLocation.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("new message");
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent
                        .getActivity(G.context, 0, resultIntent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                ncomp.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                nManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        ncomp.build());

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? what is your problem ?

Comment: i edited my Question please read again tnx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752889/override-default-android-messaging-application

Comment: oh no,in my question i need that my application filter text message that ,it's content is just "Dbdmrs" , and in other case my application ignore this Message,understand?

Comment: you get your message with your code as you mention, i think your problem is remove notification of default sms app, am i right?

Comment: yes Exactly,my problem is remove notification of default sms app , only for a specific message("Dbdmrs") , not for all of sms

Answer (score 0):

Android manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.likith.readmessage.messageIntent">   
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.likith.readmessage.TestService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
```

messageIntent.java

```
package com.likith.readmessage;

import com.likith.lockphone.messagedialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class messageIntent extends BroadcastReceiver
{
private static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "realtime_protection"; 
SharedPreferences reader; 
boolean settings_anti_theft;

final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try 
    {
        if (bundle != null) 
        {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) 
            {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String senderNum = phoneNumber;
                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: "+ senderNum + "; message: " + message);
            } 
        } 

    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);
    }
}
```

}

TestService.java

```
package com.likith.readmessage;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class TestService extends Service 
{
public TestService() 
{
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
{
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

Comment: oh no,I said that Certain Message ,but your code is for All of the Message received,for example when a SMS received whith this content: "123456ddd123" then just my application show this Message